# Double negative simple alternative with nobody/anybody

Tags: translation, multiple-negation

In Portuguese it's very common to have negative concord, like in the common saying I'm trying to translate:

> Ninguém é melhor que ninguém

Which literally translates to

> Nobody is better than nobody

But I've seen that double negatives are not formal English and even If I were to use in a colloquial context I'm not sure it would transmit the message clearly, which is "No one is better than anyone else."

I was recommended to phrase it like this

> Nobody is better than anybody

But changing "anybody" for "nobody" seems susceptible for negative concord, so I wonder if the double negative would be fine in this case.

Which form is better? Or, is there an even better one?
Would the first translation be easily understood?

Comment: "No one is better than anyone else" is by far the clearest.

Comment: @Mick yes, it is. But common sayings have a particular need for style to become catchy, which is often achieved with repetition (e.g. "Never say never"). That's why I'm putting some effort to preserve the structure.

Comment: Mick is right. You can leave off the "else" but then you wind up with a potential confusion. Your statement could merely sound like it's saying, more or less, that "everybody sucks, they're all worthless." Adding the "else" is what I would use to express the egalitarianism you may be looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by "seems susceptible for negative concord"?

Comment: Second, *Nobody is better than nobody* is okay in  very informal contexts (compare: *I ain't got nobody*)  but not in everyday English (I don't have anybody).

Comment: Please add me to the list of people who want to know the meaning of _"seems susceptible for negative concord."_

Comment: I meant that it is a situation where usually using the double negative would yield negative concord instead of canceling negatives That is, it seems to me that very frequently, "anybody" could be changed to "nobody" in a double negative.

Comment: In  "non-standard" English you could have *ain't nobody better 'n nobody*

Comment: Haha that's a lovely expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can have your negative concord.

- There's nobody better than anybody.
- No one is better than anyone.

I don't think a double negative is a good idea to use here. It won't be idiomatic as in "Never say never" and won't add contrast to the sentence.